# Random lines in Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I realise this is a bit off shot, but I will try.

I have never experienced anything like this before - I am building an accordion for the page, and when I expand it, random lines appear below the expanded item (see image).

[image]

The most visible line is a separator and should be there, however I have no idea where the other ones come from. This quirk is not replicated in Chrome nor Mozilla.

Moreover, if I do not have web inspector opened and I open it, the lines disappear. This leads me to believe it might be some issue with painting the DOM element, possibly the mentioned `border-bottom`?

Anyone has ever experienced anything like this before? Being the perfectionist I am with OCD, I find it extremely annoying!

Comment: try to add to your animated element `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` or even `transform: translateZ(0);`

Comment: Thanks man, transform: translateZ(0) did it. Any suggestion why this was happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your animated element:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

to enable Hardware accelerated animations.
**Safari** will then remove those residual *liny* glitches.

Also `-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` might help to remove edged lines that usually appear in **Chrome** (if you apply rotations...).

Comment: This worked for me as well. It had to be applied to the element that "left the trace" - make sure that's what you do as well.